# How to change only some QTableWidgetItems in a row?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget with the following columns:

```
    Username    Password     URL       Status
   +----------+-----------+---------+---------+
   |  user1   |  passwd1  | url.com |   OK    |
   |  user2   |  passwd2  | url.com |   FAIL  |
   +----------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

In a worker `QThread` in my application, a signal is emitted containing the data displayed in the table. However, this data needs to be updated later (particularly the "Status" column).

I would like to be able to update, for example, only the second row. Now, so far I would loop over all the rows in the table and then try to match some unique field (e.g. username) with the data sent by the software. So, if the status for row 2 needs to be updated from "FAIL" to "RETRY", the signal sent to the GUI thread would contain the username and the status string. I would then compare the two strings (the one from the signal i.e. the QThread with the ones that are currently in the table), and, if there is a match, update the table. Hopefully this makes sense.

Thing is, I am wondering if this is a viable solution? Is there any other? I have considered adding another "hidden" column to the QTableWidget which will contain a string of random characters generated by every QThread, which will then be updated. But the principle is still the same.

Could anyone give me any pointers?

EDIT: Adding code per request:

This is my GUI thread code (search & update part):

```
def writeToMainTable(self, param):

    username = param['username']
    statusText = param['statusText']

    for i in xrange(self.mainTable.currentRowCount()):
        if username == self.mainTable.item(i, 0).text():
            found = True
            activerow = i    

    if found:
        if statusText is not None: self.mainTable.setItem(activerow, 3, QTableWidgetItem(statusText))
```

While the QThread have something like this:

```
def sendToTable(self, param): #param is a dict here as well
    self.mainsig.emit(param)
```

Comment: Can you show some code? It'll help to understand your situation and suggest more relevant solutions.

Comment: Can you do this as a object/viewer model, keep the 'real' version of your data in a dictionary on dictionaries keyed on some unique ID, and  the inner dictionary contains a field for which row it corresponds to.  You then write your slot to update the dictionaries first and the table later.

Comment: Added the code.

@tcaswell would that not just unnecessarily complicate things even more? I could technically just add the unique ID to the table itself, and then update it directly.

Comment: @Deusdies: I meant the code you are using to populate the table. You could just store the `QTableWidgetItem`s for your `Status` in a dict with `username`s as the key (assuming they are unique) and update the text (`setText`) of the appropriate item from that dict.

Comment: @Deusdies There is something to be said for separating your data representation (ie, how your code keeps track of it) from your data display (how the user sees it). (this is the observer design pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  If you wanted to later add the ability to save this table, you don't have to scrape it out of the table, if you want to display it differently ect, only that bit of your code has to change.  Plus, you get to leverage `dict`s for the look up step.

Comment: Take a look at `QTableWidget.findItems` You won't have to make your own loop. http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableWidget.findItems

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want.  I assume you want Qt to do the looping for you?  If so here's a way.  Hope this helps.

```
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.table = Table(self)
        self.change = QPushButton('Change')

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.change)

        self.change.clicked.connect(self.table.updateCell)

class Table(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(2, 2, parent)
        self.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem('test'))
        self.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem('False'))

    def updateCell(self):

        item, = self.findItems('test', Qt.MatchExactly)
        new = repr(not eval(self.item(item.row(), 1).text()))
        self.item(row, 1).setText(new)


app = QApplication([])  
main = Main()
main.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a different `QThread` to update each row, so you could use a [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsignalmapper.html), something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import time, random

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    statusChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.status = None

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        self.status = True if not self.status else False
        self.statusChanged.emit()


class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)  
        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)  

        for row in range(2):
            status = random.getrandbits(1)
            state  = "Ok" if status else "Failed"
            thread = MyThread(self)
            thread.status = status

            self.signalMapper.setMapping(thread, row)

            thread.statusChanged.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
            thread.start()

            values = ["user", "passwd", "url.com", state]
            for column, value in enumerate(values):
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setText("{0}: {1}".format(row, value))

                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)

        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, number):
        state  = "Ok" if self.signalMapper.mapping(number).status else "Failed"
        item   = self.tableWidget.item(number, 3)
        item.setText("{0}: {1}".format(number, state))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.resize(666, 111)
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```